# Multiple arguments not working

Tags: python, function

I am trying to make a simple function which is supposed to create 3 directories. It only creates one and i do not understand why it is so.
The code i wrote is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8

import os
from os.path import exists, splitext

def make_dir(*dirs):
    for directory in dirs:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            return os.makedirs(directory)
        else:
            print "la carpeta %s ya existe" %(directory)

make_dir("hola", "que", "tal")
```

When running the function it returns only the first directory "hola"
Any help?

Comment: `return os.makedirs(directory)` -- yup, when you get to "hola" this will return that string and exit the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you return from the function, thus it never goes on to create the subsequent files. remove the return statement